# Do a loop instead of multiple $http chaining?

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax

sorry, i have checked answers, but still dont understand how to make it :

I've got an array :

```
 var surfaces   = [     
     {min:0,max:499},
     {min:500,max:999},
     {min:1000,max:1499},
     {min:1500,max:1999},
     {min:2000,max:2399},
     {min:2400,max:2999},
     {min:3000,max:3999},
     {min:4000,max:5999},
     {min:6000,max:100000}
 ]
```

And I've got this looong $http chained calls with $q :

```
 $q.when()  
    .then(function () { 
        $http.post('backend/backend.php?action=get_normes',surfaces[0]).success(function(data){
                $scope.normes.push(data);
        })
    })
    .then(function () { 
        $http.post('backend/backend.php?action=get_normes',surfaces[1]).success(function(data){
                $scope.normes.push(data);
        })
    })
    .then(function () { 
        $http.post('backend/backend.php?action=get_normes',surfaces[2]).success(function(data){
                $scope.normes.push(data);
        })
    })
    .then(function () { 
        $http.post('backend/backend.php?action=get_normes',surfaces[3]).success(function(data){
                $scope.normes.push(data);
        })
    })
    .then(function () { 
        $http.post('backend/backend.php?action=get_normes',surfaces[4]).success(function(data){
                $scope.normes.push(data);
        })
    })
    .then(function () { 
        $http.post('backend/backend.php?action=get_normes',surfaces[5]).success(function(data){
                $scope.normes.push(data);
        })
    })
    .then(function () { 
        $http.post('backend/backend.php?action=get_normes',surfaces[6]).success(function(data){
                $scope.normes.push(data);
        })
    })
    .then(function () { 
        $http.post('backend/backend.php?action=get_normes',surfaces[7]).success(function(data){
                $scope.normes.push(data);
        })
    })
    .then(function () { 
        $http.post('backend/backend.php?action=get_normes',surfaces[8]).success(function(data){
                $scope.normes.push(data);
        })
    })
```

I'd rather do a loop, but have now idea on how to do this !!

EDIT : I've got way bigger problem : data is not in order in $scope.normes ! Its always different ! How could i do to always push in order ? How could the data could be in order ?

I got ng-repeats like this but the information is not well ordered because of $http synchornicity ;

```
<div class="row ">
                 <div class="col-lg-10" style="overflow: auto; max-height: 600px;">
                     <table  class="table table-bordered table-hover  " border="1" >
                        <thead >
                              <tr> 
                                <th> Désignation</th>
                                <th> Total Magasins</th>
                                <th> Moy Habitants Zone</th>
                                <th> Ca Moyen</th>
                                <th> EO Mini</th>
                                <th> EO Maxi</th>
                                <th> Coef Moyen</th>
                                <th> Pourcent Côtier</th>
                                <th> Pourcent Urbain</th>
                                <th> Tx Habituels</th>
                                <th> Tx fréquentation</th>
                                <th> Tx fidélisation</th>
                                <th> Zone Attraction</th>
                                <th> Revenus Zone</th>
                                <th> Nb Perso Foyer</th>
                                <th> Age Moyen</th>
                              </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody >
                          <tr  ng-repeat="norme in normes" >
                             <td>Surface 0-499 m²</td>
                             <td>{{::norme.nb_magasins | number:0}}</td>
                             <td>{{::norme.moy_habitants_zone | number:0}}</td>
                             <td>{{::norme.ca_moyen | number:0}}</td>
                             <td>{{::norme.eomin | number:0}}</td>
                             <td>{{::norme.eomax | number:0}}</td>
                             <td>{{::norme.coef_moyen | number:2}}</td>
                             <td></td>
                             <td></td>
                             <td>{{::norme.tx_habituels | number:2}}</td>
                             <td>{{::norme.tx_frequentation | number:2}}</td>
                             <td>{{::norme.tx_fidelisation | number:2}}</td>
                             <td>{{::norme.attraction | number:0}}</td>
                             <td>{{::norme.revenus_zone | number:0}}</td>
                             <td>{{::norme.nb_pers_foyer | number:2}}</td>
                             <td>{{::norme.age_moyen | number:2}}</td>
                             <td ></td>
                          </tr>


                        </tbody>

                    </table>
                </div>
```

Each time i redo the $q, it comes with a different order ! How could i do ?

**EDIT :** So I'm now getting standards JSON objects from the Back End so it is simplier(Editied the html table on this post), but with the solutions you gently provided, it doesnt appear yet in the right order. The $http get started in the right order, but it seems that $scope.normes doesnt list as the $http have been started ! (Oh i think i maybe can order with the orderby in the front end... I forgot, but i thought it was possible to order the json objects as they get pushed into the array, but in the view it doesnt appear as when the $http have been called)

Comment: you can use angular built-in function `forEach` to handles multiples async http calls

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
$scope.onAllDone = function() {
    var promises = [];

    angular.forEach(surfaces , function(surface) {
        promises.push($http.post('backend/backend.php?action=get_normes',surface)).then(function(data) {
            $scope.normes.push(data);
            return data;
        });
    });

    return $q.all(promises);
}

USE::

$scope.onAllDone().then(fnSuccess, fnError);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i'm trying.

Comment: Sorry I've got this error, Error: promises.push(...).then is not a function. But it seems to be a great code thank you

Answer (score 0):

Promises and $q.all ([doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)) are your friends.

In more detail, you will have to make a promise for each call (if the call itself does not return one), push them in an array and call $q.all(promises).then(allFinished).

```
function callUpdate(x, promises) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    $http.post('backend/backend.php?action=get_normes',x).then(function(resp){
        $scope.normes.push(resp.data); 
        d.resolve(resp.data);
    })
    promises.push(d.promise);
}

...
var promises = [];
$scope.normes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < surfaces.length; i++) {
    callUpdate(surfaces[i], promises);
}

$q.all(promises).then(function() {
    // called when all promises have been resolved successully
});
```

Comment: Yes it works very well, thank you a lot !  unfortunatly i haven't got the results in the right order, each times it's in a differente order .i think because i'm doing an ng-repeat on an array of array, with numbers as indexes ... Its seems like it is puching into $scope.normes with a differente order each times and giving diffrent index , i dont even understand how , because as there is a promise, that would be supposed to push in the right order.

Comment: Glad that it works. :). Oh, you can use orderBy filter in ng-repeat

Comment: you know $http.post is asynchronous. So, you will never know which 1 is finish first. You can order it later after you get all the results.

Comment: Ok, so I'm now trying to create objects instead of arrays in my back-end which made no sense, I will create another question about that, because i dont know how to ng-repeat several times in one same table over an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of promises

```
var promises = [];
surfaces.forEach(function(surface){
    promises.push($http.post('backend/backend.php?action=get_normes',surface));
})
```

You can use `$q.all()` and wait for all promises to complete and use [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to create `$scope.normes` array.

```
 $q.all(promises).then(function (results) {
    $scope.normes = [].concat.apply([],results);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When chaining promises, it is important to **return** the subsequent promise to the `.then` method handler function:

```
var arrayPromise = $q.when([])  
    .then(function (dArray) { 
        var httpPromise = $http.post('backend/backend.php/action=get_normes',surfaces[0])
        var dPromise = httpPromise.then(function(response) {
            $scope.normes.push(response.data);
            dArray.push(response.data);
            return dArray;
        });
        return dPromise;
    }).then(function(dArray) {
        console.log("one XHR is complete");
        console.log(dArray);
    });
```

When the code fails to return anything to the handler function, the $q service resolves the promise as `undefined` and immediately executes the next function. By returning the subsequent promise, the $q service will wait for the promise to resolve before executing the next promise in the chain.

---

That said. How to create a loop that chains sequential promises?

```
var arrayPromise = $q.when([]);

for (let n=0; n<surfaces.length; i++) {  
    arrayPromise = arrayPromise
      .then(function (dArray) { 
        var httpPromise = $http.post(url,surfaces[n]);
        var dPromise = httpPromise.then(function(response) {
            $scope.normes.push(response.data);
            dArray.push(response.data);
            //return dArray to chain
            return dArray;
        });
        return dPromise;
    });
};

arrayPromise.then(function(dArray) {
    console.log("all XHRs are complete");
    console.log(dArray);
}).catch(function(errorResponse) {
    console.log("one of the XHRs failed");
    console.log(errorResponse.status);
    throw errorResponse;
});
```

Create a variable with a promise for an empty array. Then in the loop simply assign the promise derived from the `.then` method back to that variable. Each iteration of the loop **returns** an array that is one item larger than the previous iteration. Also each iteration has the side effect of pushing an item to scope.